# How to convert time stamp string from 24 hr format to 12 hr format in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, formatting, type-conversion, timestamp

I am working on flutter application where i have to show time stamps but the response i got from api is in 24 hr format and i want to display time in 12 hr format in my application.[image: Here is the json response from api]

**And i want to display on application in this format** [image: I want in this format]
Can you please help me regarding the easiest way of doing the formatting from 24 hr to 12 hr?

Answer (score 20):

Dart `intl` framework helps you to format date/time into any type you want.

https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Especially for your case, you can use this code.

```
DateFormat("h:mma").format(date);
```

Answer (score 19):

@Umair, as Sam pointed out, you can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package and can use jm() function without explicitly declaring the format like so,

**For default** `DateTime`

```dart
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(new DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.now()), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                )
            )
        ));
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

**For 24 hr timestamp string**

```dart
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String timeStamp24HR = "2020-07-20T18:15:12";

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(new DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.parse(timeStamp24HR)), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                )
            )
        ));
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: 24hr time string]

More info on Flutter's parse method here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: How do you do this with 24-hour format? Your method is only for 12-hour format.

Answer (score 8):

To convert UTC time to local time with the specified format including date

Import the below package:

```
package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Convert like below:

```
var dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa"); // you can change the format here
var utcDate = dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(uTCTime)); // pass the UTC time here
var localDate = dateFormat.parse(utcDate, true).toLocal().toString();
String createdDate = dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(localDate)); // you will get local time
```

Comment: It will be better if you mention the package for using DateFormat class, which is 'import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
'

Answer (score 6):

Use Function from `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';` library.

`DateFormat.Hm().format(date);`

it will give a 24 hours format time `23:30`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use TimeOfDay class:

```
var time = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now());
print(time.hourOfPeriod);
print(time.minute);
print(time.period);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to import `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';` at the top of your file. Then `DateFormat("h:mma")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat().add_yMMMEd().add_jms().format(now);
```

O/p:Thu,jul 14,2022 4:50:24 PM

Answer (score 4):

```
  String utcTo12HourFormat(String bigTime) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(bigTime);
    var dateFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a"); // you can change the format here
    var utcDate = dateFormat.format(tempDate); // pass the UTC time here
    var localDate = dateFormat.parse(utcDate, true).toLocal().toString();
    String createdDate = dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(localDate));
    print("------------$createdDate");
    return createdDate;
  }
```

Comment: DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(bigTime);
this is wrong because 12PM will not work
DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(bigTime);
this is correct

Comment: @IlyasArafath This little thing you mentioned saved me. Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

The below example shows how to get time from the picker and convert it using `DateFormat("h:mm a")`, here a denotes `AM and PM`

```
TimeOfDay? _selectedTime;

Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? timePicked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (timePicked != null)
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = timePicked;
      });
    // Conversion logic starts here
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(
        _selectedTime!.hour.toString() +
            ":" + _selectedTime!.minute.toString());
    var dateFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a"); // you can change the format here
    print(dateFormat.format(tempDate));
  }
```

**Output:**

flutter: 8:00 PM

Answer (score 2):

input: 23:43

```
  var time = "12:00";
  var temp = int.parse(time.split(':')[0]);
  String? t;
  if(temp >= 12 && temp <24){
    t = " PM";
  }
  else{
    t = " AM";
  }
  if (temp > 12) {
    temp = temp - 12;
    if (temp < 10) {
      time = time.replaceRange(0, 2, "0$temp");
      time += t;
    } else {
      time = time.replaceRange(0, 2, "$temp");
      time += t;
    }
  } else if (temp == 00) {
    time = time.replaceRange(0, 2, '12');
    time += t;
  }else{
    time += t;
  }
```

output: 11:43 PM

Answer (score 1):

```
String time24to12Format(String time) {
int h = int.parse(time.split(":").first);
int m = int.parse(time.split(":").last.split(" ").first);
String send = "";
if (h > 12) {
  var temp = h - 12;
  send =
      "0$temp:${m.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + m.toString() : m.toString()} " +
          "PM";
} else {
  send =
      "$h:${m.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + m.toString() : m.toString()}  " +
          "AM";
}

return send;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here are almost all the conversions of Date and time you can use in any Flutter app. This library will help you out in almost each format for date and time both `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

###### `24hr -> 12 hr format:`

```
var to12HrFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa")
    .format(yourDateandTime)  //if your datetime is in DateTime type use this method
       
var to12HrFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa") 
    .format(DateTime.parse(yourDateandTime)); //if your datetime is in String type use this method
```

if you only want to convert time only just change the format from `DateFormat(dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa)` to `DateFormat(hh:mm aa)`

###### `12hr -> 24 hr format:`

```
DateTime to24HrFormat= DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse(yourAMPMTime); // if you want type in DateTime
String to24HrFormat= DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(yourAMPMTime); //if you want the return type in String
```

here is a little explanation of Type Conversion in time

`String -> DateTime:`

```
  static DateTime parseStringDate(String dateString,
  {String format = 'yyyy-MM-d', bool localFromUTc = false}) {
if (dateString.isEmpty) return DateTime.now();
if (dateString.contains('am') || dateString.contains('pm')) {
  dateString =
      dateString.replaceFirst(' pm', ' PM').replaceFirst(' am', ' AM');
}
var date = DateFormat(format).parse(dateasString, localFromUTc).toLocal(); //for DateTime to String conversion use .format(dateasDateTime) in place of .parse()
return date;
 }
```

`Date In Format:`

```
  static String getDateInFormat(DateTime dateTime,
  {String format = 'd/M/yyyy'}) {
return DateFormat(format).format(dateTime);
}
```

if you only want a single item from date like day, month or year
pass `dd` for day `MMMM` for month and `yyyy` in format in above function.