# How to format 24 hour DateTime to 12 hour?

Tags: flutter, datetime, datetime-format

I am working on this app and the project is running smoothly. A big part of the app is that it shows what time data was entered but I can't figure out to get the time out of the 24-hour format as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Already looked at some solutions but I can't figure out how to implement them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert time stamp string from 24 hr format to 12 hr format in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270847/how-to-convert-time-stamp-string-from-24-hr-format-to-12-hr-format-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateFormat.  For example:

```
final myDate = DateTime.now();
final formattedDate = DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a').format(myDate);
```

Just change the format string that you pass as the first parameter to DateFormat to specify the format you want.